# github code search api always return 404

Tags: python, api, curl, github, github-api

According to the [docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) I can call code search API 5 times per minute without any credentials.
So I should be able to use python requests:

```
import requests
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Awesome-Octocat-App'}
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=chembl", headers=user_agent)
```

but unfortunately it's not ok:

```
r.ok
>>> False
r.status_code
>>> 404
```

And my headers look fine:

```
r.request.headers
>>> {'Accept': '*/*',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress',
 'Content-Length': '0',
 'User-Agent': 'Awesome-Octocat-App'}
```

Just let me add that this link:

```
https://github.com/search?q=chembl
```

returns 17 results.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set a special user agent. http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required

EDIT : You also must provide a custom media type in the Accept header according to this page : developer.github.com/v3/search

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/search/ here it says that "you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header"

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub Search API is [currently available in "preview mode"](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-07-19-preview-the-new-search-api/#preview-period).   To access the API during the preview period, you must [specify a custom media type in the Accept header](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#preview-mode):

```
application/vnd.github.preview
```

The preview period allows developers to test out the new API and share their feedback with GitHub before the API is declared stable and suitable for production use. The preview period began on July 19, 2013, and it is expected to last for roughly 60 days. At the *end* of the preview period, you will no longer need to specify this custom media type in the Accept header.